# How to copy an S3 bucket onto Kubernetes nodes

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, kops, daemonset

I wanted to copy an S3 bucket on Kubernetes nodes as a DaemonSet, as the new node will also get the s3 bucket copy as soon it gets launched,
I prefer an S3 copy to the Kubernetes node because copying S3 to directly to the pod as an AWS API would mean multiple calls as multiple pods require it and it will take time to copy content each time when the pod is launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your S3 content is static and doesn't change often. I believe more than a [`DaemonSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) it makes more sense to use a one time [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) to copy the whole S3 bucket to a local disk. It's not clear how you would signal the kube-scheduler that your node is not ready until the S3 bucket is fully copied. But, perhaps you can [`taint`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) your node before the job is finished and remove the taint after the job finishes.

Note also that S3 is inherently slow and meant to be used for processing (reading/writing) single files at a time, so if your bucket has a large amount of data it would take a long time to copy to the node disk.

If your S3 content is dynamically (constantly changing) then it would be more challenging since you would have to files in sync. Your apps would probably have to cache architecture where you would go to the local disk to find files and if they are not there, then make a request to S3.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that helped lot. In our case S3 content in wont change daily, its static files which will updated every 3 to 4 months once. Your last comment make sense we will rethink.